# Impyla - getting SASL error for identical code on different server

Tags: python, thrift, sasl, impyla

We have a script using impyla that queries one server from another. It works fine and has no issues. We then copied the Anaconda environment to a different server with the exact same configuration as the original and tried the same script again and keep getting this error:

`thriftpy2.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found'")`

Why does it not work on a different server? Everything seems to be identical, such as the `krb5.conf`, all the package versions, python version, etc.